# How to Modify a Record in Selected Excel Worksheet among Multiple sheets Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, record

I have a Excel data entry form and two Excel database tables as Table1 and Table2. In the data entry form I have given an option to select either Table1 or Table2 and I want to modify Either Table1 record or Table2 record according to my table selection using modify button in the data entry form. Table record should be modified according to the serial number. But when I select a Table and going to modify a record in the selected table using serial number an error is showing as "No Record found". Why is that? How to fix this?
module1 coding for modifying a record is given below

```
Sub ModifyRecord()
    
    

    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iSerial As Long
    
    iSerial = Application.InputBox("Please enter Serial Number to make modification.", "Modify", , , , , , 1)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    iRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError _
    (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSerial, Sheets("Database").Range("A:A"), 0), 0)
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If iRow = 0 Then
     
        MsgBox "No record found.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Record"
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
    
    Sheets("Form").Range("L1").Value = iRow
    Sheets("Form").Range("M1").Value = iSerial
    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H9").Value = Sheets("Database").Cells(iRow, 2).Value
     
    Sheets("Form").Range("H11").Value = Sheets("Database").Cells(iRow, 3).Value
    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H13").Value = Sheets("Database").Cells(iRow, 4).Value
    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H15").Value = Sheets("Database").Cells(iRow, 5).Value
    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H17").Value = Sheets("Database").Cells(iRow, 6).Value
    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H19").Value = Sheets("Database").Cells(iRow, 7).Value
    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H21").Value = Sheets("Database").Cells(iRow, 8).Value
    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H23").Value = Sheets("Database").Cells(iRow, 9).Value
    
    
    
End Sub

sheet1(form) coding for modifying a record is given below

Private Sub cmdModify_Click()

    Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to modify the record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Modify Record")
    
        If msgValue = vbYes Then
        
            Call ModifyRecord
            
        End If
       
End Sub
```

How to fix this error. please help  me

Comment: Remove / comment out your `on error` statements and what is the error that comes up?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I didn't see Table1 or Table2 in the code. On my test data, your code works as written, without errors. Perhaps there is really no Serial Number in the Database!A:A column that you enter into the form?

Comment: should I include Table1 and Table2 in the code? There is serial no column in the database. This code really works for single database. But when I give option to select a Table in the data entry form this problem arises, I think this code does not detect the selection of Tables. please help me to sort out this problem and thank you very much for your time